# Polymorphism with QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant, qmetatype

I have two classes like this :

> ```
> class Foo
> {
> public:
>    Foo(int i) : _i(i) {}
>    int _i;
> };
> Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo*)
> ```

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
   Bar(int i, int j) : Foo(i), _j(j) {}
   int _j;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Bar*)
```

My bench is like this :

> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
> {        
>     QApplication a(argc, argv);             
>     Bar* bar = new Bar(10,11);
>     QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(bar);
>     Foo * foo = var.value<Foo*>();            // foo IS NULL      
>     QPushButton * b = new QPushButton();
>     QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(b);
>     QObject * object = v.value<QObject*>();       // object  IS NOT NULL
>     return a.exec();
> }
> ```

Why is `foo` null ? 
`QVariant` lets the polymorphism since I have no problem with `object`

Comment: Just a thought, but would you need to declare the metatype for Bar, as well as Foo, since Bar is also a custom type for QVariant? As the docs state "Note: If you are working with custom types, you should use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() macro to register your custom type."

Comment: Sorry, Bar is also declared as metatype.

Comment: did you register types?

Comment: Yes I tried :    
    qRegisterMetaType<Foo*>("Foo*");
    qRegisterMetaType<Foo>("Foo");

    qRegisterMetaType<Bar*>("Bar*");
    qRegisterMetaType<Bar>("Bar");

but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Foo` is not derived from `QObject` and `QVariant` only supports polymorphism for `QObject`-derived types.

From the [QVariant::value documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value):

> If the QVariant contains a pointer to a type derived from QObject then T may be any QObject type. If the pointer stored in the QVariant can be qobject_cast to T, then that result is returned. Otherwise a null pointer is returned. **Note that this only works for QObject subclasses which use the Q_OBJECT macro.**

(Emphasis mine). This is rehashed in the part about `QVariant::canConvert` that is referenced further down, and there is nothing else about pointer conversions. `QVariant` simply does not support your scenario.

The upside is that if you make `Foo` a subclass of `QObject`, you do not have to bother with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that there is no meta data about inheritance and no virtual table, so `QVariant` has no data about inheritance. You can try add some virtual method to base class (destructor would be best), it might help (in such case there will be some run time data about inheritance) but I don't think it is enough.
Like in other answer this feature will work for sure for `QObject`s.

You can also try add `Q_GADGET` macro to provide meta data, but I doubt it will solve the problem.